# flutter_test from sdk is incompatible with tiled >=0.4.0. when adding flame: ^0.24.0 dependencies

Tags: flutter

I added flame: ^0.24.0 dependency in my pubspec.yaml file but I dont know why I am getting this error:

C:\flutter\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color packages get
Running "flutter pub get" in boxgame...
Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on xml 3.5.0 and tiled >=0.4.0 depends on xml ^4.2.0, flutter_test from sdk is incompatible with tiled >=0.4.0.

And because flame >=0.24.0 depends on tiled ^0.6.0, flutter_test from sdk is incompatible with flame >=0.24.0.

So, because boxgame depends on both flame ^0.24.0 and flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because boxgame depends on both flame ^0.24.0 and flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1

Code of my pubspec.yaml:

```
name: boxgame
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flame: ^0.24.0


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages


[Error][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4uaO.png
```

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar issue with dependencies on my project, Running this resolved my issue.

```
dart pub upgrade --null-safety
```

It validates and checks for compatibility of the dependencies and updates them accordingly rather than showing just an incompatibility error

Comment: Please, describe, why this should solve the problem to provide a *way* to resolve some issues, but not *do like this* code. It will help future readers to find the solution by themselves

Comment: @astentx sorry it's my first answer to anyone's question. I tried updating it to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks Man It is really working in my case

Answer (score 1):

You could try removing the 'flutter_test' dependency, if you're not using it.

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Or use a slightly older version of 'flame'

```
  flame: ^0.22.1
```

Which depends on the same version of 'tiled' as 'flutter_test'

Comment: I just add flame:                                                                                                                                         and nothing else and it worked...Thanks for the answer though